# Add argparse arguments on the go

Tags: python, argparse

So basically, I have 10-50 additional parameter configurations that I want to potentially send into the script via `argparse` - and I don't want to configure them all in the python script.

It's only me running the script, so there is no security issue. Is there any way I could call my script with

```
python myScript.py -parameter value -parameter2 value2 -parameter30 value30
```

without having set up any of the `parameter` as arguments in my script? Or anything else with the same effect -- the `**kwargs` analogue of functions?

Comment: you can just transform it into key-value pairs, then a dict and use it directly if you want, no need to use argsparse

Comment: There are previous SO questions about parsing generalized `key=value` inputs.  But `argparse` is really aimed at giving you, the programmer, control over the structure of the inputs.  For freeform input it may be easier to read the `sys.argv` list directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are your configuration parameters defined ?  If your program has a list of such parameters, you can always use a loop to  add all parameters.

```
for parameter_name in parameter_names:
    argparser.add_argument( '--' + parameter_name, action='store', metavar='<string>' )
```

There is no way to auto-parse unknown options, because there is no way whether you want 0, 1 or many arguments associated with an unknown option.  However you can delay parsing of unknown options using [`parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args).